# Is there any way to download folder and files for specific user using box api?

Tags: box-api

I have a user which has co-admin privileages. i HAVE ACCESS AND AUTH TOKEN CORRESPONDING TO CO-ADMIN. In my code I first fetch all the users present under given enterprise account and then for some specific users i want to download all the folders and files. Is there any way to do so?. I know that box api does have GetFolder(). but this api does not take any arguments such as username . It requires a folder id and It will always return all the folders and files under that id.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the [On-Behalf-Of header](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-on-behalf-of-enterprise-user). Once you've authenticated an admin account, you can use this header to make any API call on behalf any of the users in the admin's enterprise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I checked the link posted by you. It seems we need to drop a mail to api@box.com for enabling this feature.i have a question. Does this mean that for every different api key, i need to first get a access by writing mail to api@box.com?? I am trying to create an application wherein once we have co-admin auth token we can access all the files of the different users. If I have to support multiple companies where each company will have a separate api key for their coadmin.then Do i need to first get access for all those clients .